# Someone knows how to solve error permission denied

Tags: 14.04

> Title and contents of this question have been translated from Portuguese into English via Google Translate. The translation is below (Note: human intervention on the automatically generated text):

Whatever I try to do in Ubuntu, it appears this message: `Permission Denied`

I have done everything but it doesn't change.

Comment: Some commands require that you use `sudo` to run them with superuser privileges. If `command` doesn't work, you can run `sudo command`. (If someone wants to, feel free to expand on this and make it into an answer)

Answer (score 2):

Permission is denied when user is not a superuser. not any person can modify your root files (system files).unless u provide authentication to your own machine that you are the superuser. For doing any superuser operation like install remove u have to use the keyword 'sudo' for eg.sudo apt-get update
It will ask you to enter your password(which is not visible when typed) then you can do your operation.